# Shasum output of signature keys not matching

Tags: security

My shasum output does not match ANY keys listed on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/builder-keys/keys.txt ?

**shasum -a 256 bitcoin-22.0-osx-signed.dmg
f33c27745f2bd87344be790465ef984a972fd539dc83bd4f61d4242c607ef1ee  bitcoin-22.0-osx-signed.dmg**

9D3CC86A72F8494342EA5FD10A41BDC3F4FAFF1C Aaron Clauson (sipsorcery)
617C90010B3BD370B0AC7D424BB42E31C79111B8 Akira Takizawa (akx20000)
E944AE667CF960B1004BC32FCA662BE18B877A60 Andreas Schildbach (aschildbach)
152812300785C96444D3334D17565732E08E5E41 Andrew Chow (achow101)
590B7292695AFFA5B672CBB2E13FC145CD3F4304 Antoine Poinsot (darosior)
0AD83877C1F0CD1EE9BD660AD7CC770B81FD22A8 Ben Carman (benthecarman)
912FD3228387123DC97E0E57D5566241A0295FA9 BtcDrak (btcdrak)
04017A2A6D9A0CCDC81D8EC296AB007F1A7ED999 Carl Dong (dongcarl)
C519EBCF3B926298946783EFF6430754120EC2F4 Christian Decker (cdecker)
18AE2F798E0D239755DA4FD24B79F986CBDF8736 Chun Kuan Le (ken2812221)
101598DC823C1B5F9A6624ABA5E0907A0380E6C3 CoinForensics (CoinForensics)
F20F56EF6A067F70E8A5C99FFF95FAA971697405 centaur (centaur)
C060A6635913D98A3587D7DB1C2491FFEB0EF770 Cory Fields (cfields)
BF6273FAEF7CC0BA1F562E50989F6B3048A116B5 Dev Random (devrandom)
6D3170C1DC2C6FD0AEEBCA6743811D1A26623924 Douglas Roark (droark)
948444FCE03B05BA5AB0591EC37B1C1D44C786EE Duncan Dean (dunxen)
1C6621605EC50319C463D56C7F81D87985D61612 Emanuele Cisbani (cisba)
9A1689B60D1B3CCE9262307A2F40A9BF167FBA47 Erik Mossberg (erkmos)
D35176BE9264832E4ACA8986BF0792FBE95DC863 fivepiece (fivepiece)
6F993B250557E7B016ADE5713BDCDA2D87A881D9 Fuzzbawls (Fuzzbawls)
01CDF4627A3B88AAE4A571C87588242FBE38D3A8 Gavin Andresen (gavinandresen)
D1DBF2C4B96F2DEBF4C16654410108112E7EA81F Hennadii Stepanov (hebasto)
A2FD494D0021AA9B4FA58F759102B7AE654A4A5A Ilyas Ridhuan (IlyasRidhuan)
2688F5A9A4BE0F295E921E8A25F27A38A47AD566 James O'Beirne (jamesob)
D3F22A3A4C366C2DCB66D3722DA9C5A7FA81EA35 Jarol Rodriguez (jarolrod)
7480909378D544EA6B6DCEB7535B12980BB8A4D3 Jeffri H Frontz (jhfrontz)
D3CC177286005BB8FF673294C5242A1AB3936517 jl2012 (jl2012)
82921A4B88FD454B7EB8CE3C796C4109063D4EAF Jon Atack (jonatack)
32EE5C4C3FA15CCADB46ABE529D4BCB6416F53EC Jonas Schnelli (jonasschnelli)
4B4E840451149DD7FB0D633477DFAB5C3108B9A8 Jorge Timon (jtimon)
C42AFF7C61B3E44A1454CD3557AF762DB3353322 Karl-Johan Alm (kallewoof)
70A1D47DD44F59DF8B22244333E472FE870C7E5D Kristaps Kaupe (kristapsk)
30DE693AE0DE9E37B3E7EB6BBFF0F67810C1EED1 Lisa Neigut (niftynei)
E463A93F5F3117EEDE6C7316BD02942421F4889F Luke Dashjr (luke-jr)
B8B3F1C0E58C15DB6A81D30C3648A882F4316B9B Marco Falke (marco)
07DF3E57A548CCFB7530709189BBB8663E2E65CE Matt Corallo (BlueMatt)
CA03882CB1FC067B5D3ACFE4D300116E1C875A3D MeshCollider (meshcollider)
E777299FC265DD04793070EB944D35F9AC3DB76A Michael Ford (fanquake)
AD5764F4ADCE1B99BDFD179E12335A271D4D62EC Michael Tidwell (miketwenty1)
9692B91BBF0E8D34DFD33B1882C5C009628ECF0C Michagogo (michagogo)
C57E4B42223FDE851D4F69DD28DF2724F241D8EE midnightmagic (midnightmagic)
F4FC70F07310028424EFC20A8E4256593F177720 Oliver Gugger (guggero, Oliver Gugger)
D62A803E27E7F43486035ADBBCD04D8E9CCCAC2A Paul Rabahy (prab)
37EC7D7B0A217CDB4B4E007E7FAB114267E4FA04 Peter Todd (petertodd)
D762373D24904A3E42F33B08B9A408E71DAAC974 Pieter Wuille [Location: Leuven, Belgium] (sipa)
133EAC179436F14A5CF1B794860FEB804E669320 Pieter Wuille (sipa)
6A8F9C266528E25AEB1D7731C2371D91CB716EA7 Sebastian Falbesoner (theStack)
A8FC55F3B04BA3146F3492E79303B33A305224CB Sebastian Kung (TheCharlatan)
ED9BDF7AD6A55E232E84524257FF9BDBCC301009 Sjors Provoost (sjors)
867345026B6763E8B07EE73AB6737117397F5C4F Stephan Oeste (Emzy)
9EDAFF80E080659604F4A76B2EBB056FD847F8A7 Stephan Oeste (Emzy)
6DEEF79B050C4072509B743F8C275BC595448867 Tomas Kanocz (KanoczTomas)
AEC1884398647C47413C1C3FB1179EB7347DC10D Warren Togami (wtogami)
74E2DEF5D77260B98BC19438099BAD163C70FBFA Will Clark (will8clark)
79D00BAC68B56D422F945A8F8E3A8F3247DBCBBF Willy Ko (willyko)
71A3B16735405025D447E8F274810B012346C9A6 Wladimir J. van der Laan (laanwj)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the shasum command computes an SHA hash it does not check a signature.

I would follow the instructions at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/contrib/builder-keys for importing the developer keys into gpg and then use the verification script as described at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/contrib/verifybinaries